# Is it possible to use imported classes in Apache Phoenix UDFs?

Tags: java, hbase, udf, apache-phoenix

I wrote some UDFs for Phoenix, and outsourced some functions in other classes, because they are used in multiple UDFs. Now if I register a function and execute it, I get a ClassNotFoundException for the helper class which is imported into the UDF class. Is there a way to prevent this error or do I have put all the logic within the UDF class?

Answer (score 0):

The dependencies need to be available in the classpath. Compile these to jars and place them in the Phoenix lib folder.